# i want to assign 9 to an array at i(9-1) but is undefined

Tags: c++14

I need to set the last element inside an array by multiply the last "i" with it self like this. but when i try to do i*i, i is undefined. also, when i try to print the result, cout is undefined.

```
void firstArray(void)
{
    int MyArray[10] ;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {   
        MyArray[i] = i;
    }

    MyArray [9] = i*i;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {   
    cout(MyArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried to put MyArray [9] = i*i inside the loop; with a condition( and it whould work), but i cant use any if for this assignment.

also,  I tried to put with System.out like in java before cout, but System is undefined.

what do i need to change to make it work?

Comment: Because `i` is declared only in the scope of the `for` loop. If you use it outside the loop, compiler will return an error. You cannot use it outside.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first of all, if you want "i" outside of your loop, you need to initialize "i" outside of your loop too.
`... Unsigned int i; for(i =0; i<10; i++) ...`
Now, "i" will be equal the last increment outside your loop.
Also, i suggest you to read the basics for c++, System dont exist in c++, instead its with std namespace.
There is two way to do that:

```
Using namespace std;
```

Inside the function, or by write "std::" before cout and:

```
Std::cout << MyArray[i]
```

Pay attention how i wrote it, you will find
How to do in the c++ website:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/